# In Assembly, How do i get past the -128 to 127 range?

Tags: assembly, integer-overflow, underflow

So I have this declaration in .bss

```
answer resb 1
```

In answer, I store the results of the sum of 2 digit integers ranging from -99 to +99. When I try adding  +99 and +99, the answer becomes negative. Any answer within the -128 to 127 range are inputted correctly. How do I resolve this overflow/underflow issue?

I am just beginning in Assembly coding so help me understand this issue. I've tried making resb as resw but my code just produced an "floating point error" when ran so I reverted to using resb.

How i print the answer

```
;ansh,anso,anst are all declared as resb 1 in .bss
print_answer: ;tens1 holds the answer always
;getting each digit of tens2 to be converted as char    
mov al,[answer]
mov bl,100
div bl

mov [ansh],al ; holds tens digit of average
mov [anst],ah

mov ah,0
mov al,[anst]
mov bl,10
div bl

mov [anst],al
mov [anso],ah

add byte[ansh],30h
add byte[anst],30h
add byte[anso],30h

;printing routine follows here
```

Comment: Use a larger datatype.

Comment: .. meaning 16 or 32 bit registers and memory operands.

Answer (score 0):

Adding -99 and +99 should work just fine in 8 bit registers.  If it doesn't, either the addition is not being done correctly, or the display of the result is mishandled.

A common display error is calling a library function with the 8 bit result but passing it to a function expecting a 16-bit (or wider) value.  Be sure to mask off or zero the bits you did not generate when creating the value to pass to the library function.

When doubling +99, of course the result is greater than 127, so you would either have to handle the result as an unsigned 8-bit value, or extend it to a wider value.  How are you viewing the result?

Comment: Adding +99 and -99 works fine, but +99 and +99 doesn't as I stated in my question.

Comment: @nowrn29:  Oh sorry!  I missed the subtly and have amended my answer.

Comment: First i divide answer by 100, then i store the answer as the hundreds digit, then i divide the remainder from that operation with 10 and store the answer as the tens digit and the remainder as the ones digit. As for the symbol of the answer, i have a conditional statement that checks it. I'll edit my post and show it.

Comment: how do I extend it to a wider value?